# Class defined in VC not recognized in other classes

Tags: ios, swift, import, nsobject

I am new to Swift and have created a class within a view controller class using the code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Speech
import Alamofire
//import SwiftyJSON

class VC: UIViewController {

//various code

    public class Contact: NSObject {
        var first: String = ""
        var second: String = ""
    }
/more code
}
```

However, when I try to access it in another class in the same project with the code:

```
var myContact: Contact?
```

I get an error:

> Use of undeclared type Contact.

My understanding is that you don't need to import classes in Swift.  Everything in the same module is supposed to know about everything subject to some controls.  I have tried calling the above class public class, open class, and class and also tried different syntax for declaring the variable in the other class above but keep getting the error:

> Use of undeclared type 'Contact'

It is impossible to access a class created in another class?  Or what could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any suggestions?

Comment: FYI - class, struct, and enum names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Where is declaration?  you say  `a class within a view controller` are it in ViewController file or  inside ViewController Class

Comment: @abdelahad Not sure what difference you have in mind?  the file is vc.swift.  It inherits from the UIViewController class.  Will add some code to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class Contact1: NSObject {
        var first: String = ""
        var second: String = ""
    }


    class ViewController: UIViewController {

      // or Inner class like that one

    public class Contact2: NSObject {
        var first: String = ""
        var second: String = ""
    } 

 }
```

Contact1 can be access any where  but Contact2 Can't one access by  `ViewController Type`

Comment: Oh, so I have to move it outside of the VC class?

Comment: Yes you have to do that

Comment: Awesome.  Does this affect how I initialize?  I have another line in there omitted for simplicity that says  required init(first: String, second:String) {} that is now giving an error 'required initializer must be as accessible as its enclosing type...Error seems to go away if I add public before it

Comment: where you add this `init(first: String, second:String) {}`